# Speaking of pairwise distance in groups of points

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

Once I went to my old handout and encountered this problem :

There are n points which pairwise have distance at least 1. Prove that we can choose $n/7$ points of them that pairwise have distance at least $\sqrt3$.

I've attemped for a week and I've come across to $n/12$ points with drawing rings with ratio of 1 and $\sqrt3$ over every points, there must at most 12 points in every rings.

what is your Idea about this problem?

Comment: floor(n/7) and ceil(n/7) makes a difference here. What is the case?

Comment: I'm not sure, apparently it is floor.

Comment: You should choose the points more carefully, I think you can exploit the convex hull.

Comment: Clearly false, since you didn't specify the space these points are in. In $n$-dimensional Euclidean space, it is not at all hard to find $n$ points in which all pairwise distances are exactly $1$. I am guessing you mean "points in the plane", since you talk about drawing "rings", and further $7$ has particular significance to the plane since you can have a maximum of six points at a distance of $1$ from a seventh point, and at minimum distance of $1$ from each other. But you should add that explicitly to your question.